# Remove DC offset from a Hall sensor output

Tags: dc-motor, automotive, encoder, hall-effect

Here is the test circuit for an encoder output from a car seat motor. It seems the output signal has a DC offset of 4.5-5V. How do I convert this signal to a 0-3.3V level?

[image]

Comment: I read that it outputs a signal anywhere between 4 volts and 7.5 volts and is powered from an 8 volt supply so if your **real** question is how to interface to that signal you must decide what it truly is.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean...

Comment: What information available in your question appears to imply that the output voltage is between 4 volts and 7.5 volts and not between 4.5 volts and 5 volts. I thought I was clear.

Comment: If I understand that image correctly, I think it’s a DC shifter signal that has an amplitude of 2.2V to 2.5V.

Comment: I think you might be on your own on this one.